# Can't generate random numbers

Tags: haskell, random

I can't figure out how to generate random number.

Here is how I'm trying to do according to [this](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/randoms):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let
     g <- getStdGen
     bla = randomRs (0, 360) g
```

Also tried:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let
    r <- randomIO
```

then:

> parse error on input `<-'
>   Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend one of the many great, free Haskell tutorials, such as [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) or [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/).

You can find more about `do` notation [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation).

To specifically answer your question, you are misusing the `let` keyword with `do` notation. The basic rule is: if the answer is in a monad, you should use `<-` with no `let`. If the value is not in a monad, write `let bla = ...`. You can write several such statements in a row without duplicating the `let` keyword:

```
do
  x <- y :: m a
  let z = z1
      z' = z2
      ...
  w <- w' :: m b
  z <- z' :: m c
...
```

Your code should be more like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  g <- getStdGen
  let bla = randomRs (0,360) g
```

An even better option is to use [`MonadRandom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) to hide the generator (state) completely:

```
include Control.Monad.Random

main :: IO ()
main = do
  bla <- getRandomR (0,360)
```

Comment: Although that's a good way to start, those are not complete `do` blocks, because the last statement in one must be a single expression, not a `let ...` or `... <- ...`.